# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: android-layout

I'm sorry, I'm new on this, this is my first app and the error is at line 6. Thanks

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<resources >

    <string name="app_name">Test</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string><string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>



</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *first* thing I'd be looking at is the space at the end of `resources` in the opening tag:

```
<resources >
```

Try getting rid of that.

The other thing I'd be concerned about is why you have controls and string resources in the same file.

You generally place layout stuff (like controls) into `layout/main.xml` and resources into `values/strings.xml`. These aren't hard-and-fast rules but they're the default when creating projects and they usually work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

remove the space in `<resources >`